# how to check whether div exist or not parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can we check whether  any div exit in parent div ?

Actually In my current example I am appending the div in parent div like this.

```
 $('#realTimeContents' ).append("<div style='width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;' class= 'RLTLeftDiv' ></div><div style='width:78%; float:left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;'  class= 'RLTRightDiv'></div>");
```

so when I print on console

```
console.log( $('#realTimeContents' ).html());
```

It will print this.

```
 <div style="width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class="RLTLeftDiv"></div><div style="width:78%; float:left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class="RLTRightDiv"></div>
```

I want to check if it exist in **realTimeContents** then it will true .if not exit then return false and append the given line.

Comment: I guess you meant exists?

Comment: What is exist here? `.RLTLeftDiv` or `.RLTRightDiv` or both?

Comment: oh sorry yes..you are right

Answer (score 2):

You could check it by:

```
if (!$('#realTimeContents').find('.RLTLeftDiv').length) {
  $('#realTimeContents' ).append("<div style='width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;' class= 'RLTLeftDiv' ></div><div style='width:78%; float:left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;'  class= 'RLTRightDiv'></div>");
}
```